# Why has the type of an empty array a different size within and outside of a structure?

Tags: arrays, c, structure, padding, memory-alignment

```
#include <stdio.h>    
struct Obj {
    char a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint64_t d[0];
};
struct Obj1 {
    uint64_t d[0];
};

int main() {
    uint64_t a[0];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(Obj)); // 16
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a)); // 16
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(Obj1)); // 16
    //cout << sizeof(Obj) << endl; // 16
    //cout << sizeof(a) << endl;   // 0
    //cout << sizeof(Obj1) << endl; // 0
}
```

As shown above, why the `uint64_t` variable within the struct will not be stacked right back after the `uint8_t`, and more peculiar is that the empty array has zero sizes outside the structure.

It's actually an interview question. The explanation goes like this, though still can't understand.

> If there is no fourth field, it should be 4+4+4=12, plus the fourth
> field is 16, the fourth field does not occupy space, but it will tell
> the compiler to align by 8 bytes
>
> This usage is often used in the kernel, for example, the following can
> be directly accessed by subscript

```
Obj o1; uint64_t array[1024]; // In memory, array immediately follows
o1 o1.d[123]; // can access the elements of array
```

As noted by comments, this may be only applied in C instead of C++. SO I changed the code to C version.

Comment: [Struct padding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/) due to alignment perhaps?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am sure it's not, since it's been asked in an interview.

Comment: Your arrays don't have any size.

Comment: It's definitely UB. I'm not sure why being asked that in an interview changes anything. Seems like a reasonable answer in an interview. If the interviewer said that some particular output is guaranteed, they're wrong.

Comment: What output did _you_ expect?

Comment: @BAKEZQ The interviewer is indeed wrong.  The array size has to be greater than 0: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#1.sentence-3

Comment: @BAKEZQ Interview questions are sometimes tricky, and the answer might be simply "it's undefined, anything can happen". Turn on `-pedantic` flag to see compiler complaining. [See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9YSI71hBq3p5Dhmy)

Comment: OP: Have you tried compiling this with `-pedantic`? _"warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array"_.

Comment: Clang and gcc [allow zero sized arrays](https://www.godbolt.org/z/eYKcnE) with default compiler flags, but it's indeed a non standard extension. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/r16Gwv8VP) it compiles fine and the output is the same as in the comments in the OP's code.

Comment: The code, and explanation in your latest edit may be true in c, but it's definitely not true in c++.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I expect them both to be 0.

Comment: @BAKEZQ The code in question is a variation of an outdated hack known as the "C struct hack" that was made obsolete by the introduction of ["flexible array members"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) in C99 - twenty years ago.

Comment: @AndrewHenle What does that used for(I read the wiki)? Would you plz write an answer?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The structure hack is to create an array of size 1, since compilers had to accept that, and use it with a larger allocated size, since that worked with older compilers. Use a size of 0 is a defined and supported extension in GCC, not the same as a hack.

Comment: @ryyker Content of that link is too long and wordy.

Comment: @BAKEZQ - You have got to be kidding.  Just say thank-you and study it.  You can certainly benefit from what it says.

Comment: There is no reason to think, or to interpret the program's output to indicate, that any data type has different sizes in different contexts.  In an implementation that provides zero-length arrays as an extension to standard C or C++, I would expect the size of such an array to be 0, regardless of its element type, and that is consistent with the output you report.  It is essential to understand that the size of a structure type can be greater than the combined sizes of its members, as padding bytes can be included after any member.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Even with padding(The ordinary way you are talking about), the output should be 12 instead of 16.

Comment: @BAKEZQ, any amount of padding may be included after any member.  Only by reference to implementation-specific rules for structure layout can you predict the exact size of a structure type from the types and order of the members.  Note in particular that some implementations place a pre-selected alignment requirement on all structure types, which may require trailing padding to bring structure sizes up to a multiple of (say) 8 or 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This interview question probes a candidates knowledge of alignment and certain semantics in both the C standard and specific implementations.

The `char a` member has size one (byte) and alignment requirement one (byte).

The `uint32_t b` member has size four and commonly has an alignment requirement of four bytes. In order to place it on an address that is a multiple of four bytes, the compiler has to include three unused bytes after `a` and before `b`, which are calling padding bytes. Up to this point, the structure requires 1+3+4 = 8 bytes.

The `uint8_t c` member has size one and alignment requirement one. Up to this point, the structure requires 9 bytes.

With `uint64_t d[0]`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. However, unless the interviewer has specified this is a question about strictly conforming standard C, answering that the behavior is undefined is inadequate, as there is more to C than just the standard. There is also conforming (but not strictly conforming) C and non-standard variants of C. GCC supports a well-known extension in which the last member of a structure may be declared as an array with zero elements, and the interviewer expects the questioner to be aware of this.

When such a structure is used, the program must allocate sufficient space for whatever array elements it wishes to use, by adding such space to the request made with `malloc` or a similar memory-allocation routine. For example, to allocate space for the base structure plus 13 elements, one might use `malloc(sizeof(struct Obj) + 13 * sizeof(uint64_t))`.

Commonly, a `uint64_t` has an alignment requirement of eight bytes. Whatever its alignment requirement is, the compiler will add sufficient unused bytes between members `c` and `d` to ensure `d` has the proper alignment. If it does require eight-byte alignment, then seven bytes must be inserted after `c`, so the structure size up to the start of `d` will be 1+3+4+1+7 = 16 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

First, your code is undefined behavior. From [Arrays
p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1) emphasis mine:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
>   D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt
> ```
>
> and the type of the contained
> declarator-id in the declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list
> T”, the type of the declarator-id in D is
> “derived-declarator-type-list array of N T”. The constant-expression
> shall be a converted constant expression of type std​::​size_­t
> ([expr.const]). **Its value N specifies the array bound, i.e., the
> number of elements in the array; N shall be greater than zero.**

The size of an array has to be greater then 0.

---

As for **gcc compiler extension** that [allows for zero sized arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length) in C code and happens to be also supported in C++ code, the gcc documentation states:

> Although the size of a zero-length array is zero, an array member of this kind may increase the size of the enclosing type as a result of tail padding.

Which seems to be happening in your code.

Comment: Can you explain more about the tail padding or simply add a link.